When entering date in bootstrap-table datepicker it is immediately deleted
I have a column in a bootstrap-table that is a date. And I use a filter on that column.
I have 2 ways to select the date. Clicking on the calendar and selecting the date visually. Or by entering it in a string format.
If I select it through the calendar, everything is correct. But if I enter it manually, once the days have been entered, I go on to enter the months, and the days are deleted... This is what happens with months and years too.
Do you have any idea what is happening? For me everything seems correct, could there be some conflict in the CSS and/or JS that I am loading? I'm also putting it in case it helps you in any way. Don't hesitate to ask me for anything you need.


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.29.0/tableExport.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tableexport.jquery.plugin@1.29.0/libs/jsPDF/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-table@1.22.5/dist/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

<table id="tblDates" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"
       data-locale="es-ES"
       data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-search="false"
       data-show-refresh="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-fullscreen="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-show-columns-toggle-all="true"
       data-detail-view="false"
       data-show-export="true"
       data-export-types="['json', 'xml', 'csv' , 'txt' , 'sql', 'xlsx' , 'pdf' ]"
       data-export-data-type="all"
       data-click-to-select="false"
       data-minimum-count-columns="2"
       data-show-pagination-switch="false"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-side-pagination="client"
       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, all]"
       data-show-footer="true"
       data-filter-control="true"
       data-show-search-clear-button="true"
       data-url="/Home/Refresh">
    <thead style="background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);">
        <tr>
            <th data-field="dateAdded" data-sortable="true" data-switchable="true" data-filter-control="datepicker">Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>




Could you give us a complete [mcve] with a snippet so that we may investigate your issue?

Hi @phuzi. Many thanks for helping here. Well, I tried, but is working using an online editor. For that, I suppose could be related with css and js imports.

@phuzi Maybe, as a clue. I need to click twice in the dropdown like export and so on, to get the functionality working

I've tried something similar based on the provided code and it looks lie there's a search timeout. I suspect that if that gets triggered with an invalid date the value gets reset/cleared. Entering a complete date quick enough seems to prevent the value from being cleared. Ideally you would only want the search/filter to trigger once a complete date has been entered.

@phuzi. Mmmmm... not sure. when I tried the same table on https://live.bootstrap-table.com/ I didn´t have that problem. Besides, I dont have enough time to complete the full date. Thanks

I've converted your code to a snippet and can replicate the behaviour you're experiencing. The date is cleared afterwhat seems like a 1 second pause. Typing a valid date quickly enough seems to work though!

Let us know if this is not what you were experiencing.

Well, I have to apologize. Where I don't have problems is using the date filter as a select. But if I use a datepicker as a filter, the case happens that the date is deleted and I don't have time to enter it. Forgive my inconsistency.

Oh! @phuzi. It very looks like a bug. Version 1.20.2 of bootstrap-table doesnt have the same behavior. You can, as expert, to report it if you think is necessary. Many Thanks for your help.

I'd put that as an answer that could help future readers of the question. You could then, of course, accept your own answer.

Well, I finally managed to find the problem. Everything a little crazy. This particular version of the bootstrap-table I'm using, 1.22.5 (last one), has problems entering to select the date introducing it manually. I changed the version, particularly to 1.20.2 and this problem stopped occurring.
Check here for more information about this version:
Bootstrap Table 1.20.2
